# What is the "row container" for a <ListView> component?

Tags: ios, listview, react-native

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html says:

> `removeClippedSubviews bool`
>
> A performance optimization for improving scroll perf of large lists,
>   used in conjunction with `overflow: 'hidden'` on the row containers.

And https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html says:

> `removeClippedSubviews`
>
> "When true, offscreen child views (whose overflow value is hidden) are
>   removed from their native backing superview when offscreen. This can
>   improve scrolling performance on long lists. The default value is
>   true."(The default value is false before version 0.14-rc).
>
> This is an extremely important optimization to apply on large
>   ListViews. On Android the overflow value is always hidden so you don't
>   need to worry about setting it, but on iOS you need to be sure to set
>   `overflow: hidden` on row containers.

But what is a "row container"?

```
<ListView renderRow={(r) => <Row r=r>}>
```

Do I need to apply this `overflow: hidden` to the `<ListView>` or `<Row>` styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation you shared -

> When true, offscreen child views (whose overflow value is hidden) are
>   removed from their native backing superview when offscreen.

This means that in your case you need to apply `overflow: hidden` to the `Row` component you have used in `renderRow`.